# Scheduling Posix based Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

I am using posix based threads in linux to listen on non-blocking socket.
I want to call that this thread for specific time duration e.g. for .01 sec.
Is there any way I can do that?
Thanks

Comment: Could you describe what you're trying to do in more detail? It's not very clear in your question. (Please [edit] your question to add more details.)

Comment: ?? don't understand. 'call that this thread for specific time duration e.g. for .01 sec' - you cannot call a thread, and you seem to be asking for blocking on a non-blocking socket.

Comment: I want to listen on the socket in function. Like 
void listen(){
socket_listen();
}
and don't want to stuck in this function if there is nothing to listen on socket.

Comment: the socket is non-blocking I am calling in separate function. I just want one iteration on calling functions but it gets blocked.

Comment: When you have threads, you shouldn't worrying about _stucking in a function_.

Comment: I agree with @MM. Use blocking sockets.  Use one thread per socket.  Each thread blocks listening to exactly one socket.

Comment: Or alternatively use non-blocking sockets, a single thread, and select().  That will let your single thread handle both listen() and other things simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the select() or pselect() function with a time out of 0.01 seconds. That way your thread can wait for a socket (blocking or non-blocking, it doesn't matter). When select() returns it will tell you if a socket became ready or if nothing happened in the allotted time out.